# passing color valuei from c# to aspx style class

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

net c# project . I need to pass a color value from c# code to asp.net style class . My class is

```
<style>div.timeline-event {
color: #1A1A1A;
border-color: green;
background-color:#EFD5F6;
display: inline-block;
}</style>
```

I have tried following code to pass values string

```
  MyBackgroundColor = "#EFD5F6";
```

In Page load I have declred above .

```
 div.timeline-event {
color: #1A1A1A;
border-color: green;
background-color:'<%=MyBackgroundColor %>';
display: inline-block;
}
```

But I am unable to pass it class . how can achieve this ?

Comment: Does [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147370/using-c-sharp-to-dynamically-generate-css-files) give you any hint?

Answer (score 0):

`background-color: '<%=MyBackgroundColor%>'` would be `background-color: '#EFD5F6'` in final html code. change your code to `background-color: <%=MyBackgroundColor%>` and also make sure that MyBackgroundColor is a property of your page with public/protected access modifier.