# Is it possible adding css programmatically in c# ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

my stylesheet is ;

```
.rsAptContent{ background-color: transparent !important; margin: 5px !important;}
```

is it possible creating like this in code behind ?

Comment: for specific controls or just generally for the page?

Comment: See this Question http://stackoverflow.com/q/4147370/108847

Comment: So you want to create a CSS class in code-behind (what the purpose then)? Or just want to add existing class to an element?

Comment: [Response.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525585(v=vs.90).aspx) could do that I think..

Comment: i want to create css class in code behind not existing class. For example .rscontent{bla bla..} i want to create this for general page.

Comment: do you want to create a CSS editor on your page for your page?
or do you just want a dynamical CSS class?

Answer (score 0):

css file is text file with extension .css and using StreamWriter class in C# it can be generated like any other text file

Answer (score 0):

Its a little hard to understand your question as it is not well formed, but im giving it a go, here is several possible solutions that might fit your question.

If you want to read out the css file to a textbox do this

```
//To read/load the file
Output = File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "StylesheetPath.css");
//To write/save the file
File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath) + "StylesheetPath.css", Input);
```

If you want to write the css on you page dynamically on each pageload you can do this.

```
string styles = ".rsAptContent{ background-color: transparent !important; margin: 5px !important;}"
HeaderID.InnerText = "<style>"+styles+"</style>";
```

I would not recommend doing this, at it will steal the CPU at each load, its better to change between several static stylesheet's like this

```
string stylesheet = @"\style1.css";
Head1.InnerText = "<link href=\"" + stylesheet + "\" rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" />";
```